# Django raw Query aggreation function

Tags: django, django-queryset

I need to write django raw query function to get the sum value and then write to the csn file.
 I write my query

```
for time in Tracking_details.objects.raw('SELECT *,sum=SUM(work_time) FROM structure_tracking_details WHERE employee_id='+ employee_id + ' GROUP BY project_structure ') :      
        writer.writerow([ time.project_structure,time.sum ])
```

it tells

> no such column: sum

How do I write the query correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `sum=SUM(work_time)` with `SUM(work_time) AS sum`.

BTW, `employee_id='+ employee_id + '` is a very poor way of building queries. And you **should not** do it. It makes your query prone to SQL Injection as Django doesn't check whatever query you pass in `raw()` function. You can pass parameters to the raw query like this -

```
Tracking_details.objects.raw('SELECT *, SUM(work_time) AS sum FROM structure_tracking_details WHERE employee_id = %s GROUP BY project_structure', [employee_id])
```

[More details](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#passing-parameters-into-raw).

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the comment :) I changed my query :)